# Can a class in python not use its generic parameter

Tags: python, python-typing

If I declare a function that is not using a generic parameter more than once:

```py
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar("T")

def bad(a: T) -> None:
    ...
```

a static type-checker marks this as error (or at least as a warning, if using lenient flags). But if I do something similar with *a class*:

```py
class ImBad(t.Generic[T]):
    def not_using_it(i: int) -> str:
        ...
    nor_here: int
```

there is no objection from the checker.

So my question is: Is it OK not to use a generic parameter in a class? Why anyone would do that?

Comment: are you trying to inherit from `t.Generic[T]` ?

Comment: @RuanCarloWeiersBritzke That's how it is done: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#building-generic-types

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe it's so that inherited classes can use it.

Comment: It might also be a mypy oversight. I do agree though that it might have uses for inherited classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar("T")

def bad(a: T) -> None:
    ...
```

It's possible you're misunderstanding the error message. Mypy doesn't report any errors for me (even with `--strict`), while Pyright says

```
  example.py:5:12 - warning: TypeVar "T" appears only once in generic function signature (reportInvalidTypeVarUse)
```

This isn't saying "You failed to use the type variable". It's saying "You didn't need one to begin with". A type variable in a function that's used only once can always be replaced with simple subtyping. Since your `T` is unbounded (i.e. has an implicit bound of `object`), we can replace `a: T` with `a: object` without any change to semantics.

The benefit of a type variable on a *function* comes into play when we have at least two uses of it.

```
def bad(a: T) -> None: ...
```

The type variable gives us nothing here, since it's equivalent to

```
def bad(a: object) -> None: ...
```

But

```
def add(a: T, b: T) -> Any: ...
def increment(x: T) -> T: ...
def swap(tup: tuple[T, S]) -> tuple[S, T]: ...
```

In all of these examples, the type variable(s) actually add something. `add(a: object, b: object) -> Any` wouldn't be able to guarantee that its two arguments are of the *same* type. `increment(x: object) -> object` wouldn't be able to guarantee that the result has the *same* type as the input. And `swap(tup: tuple[object, object]) -> tuple[object, object]` just discards all type information on the input for no good reason.

This is because functions never have explicit type parameters passed. That is, we never write `add[int](3, 4)`. There's just no way to even write that in Python, and even in languages that *do* allow it like C++, it's seldom done that way anyway. The point of generic functions is to add functionality without requiring the programmer to type anything additional.

Conversely, type information on a *class* is always explicitly used. If a class `Example` inherits from `Generic[T]`, then we *always* write `Example[int]` or `Example[str]`, never just `Example`.

So even if a class declares a type argument and never uses it,

1. It's possible that subclasses could use it, and
2. It's also possible that the type argument to enforce some invariant.

As an example of point (2), suppose we're talking to a C library that uses pointers. And we need a type for "pointers" in Python. As far as our hypothetical C library is concerned, these pointers are just `void*`. But we could very easily write a Python-side class like this.

```
class SmartPointer(Generic[T]):
    raw_pointer: int
```

Now our `SmartPointer` type remembers what the underlying type of the pointer is, even if our C code doesn't care. We can wrap our C functions even more intelligently than the original.